# Are Truebit questions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about Truebit on-topic and appropriate here?

[Truebit](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~teutsch/papers/truebit.pdf) is a recent proposal for building smart contracts on top of Ethereum.  Truebit allows outsourcing complex computations to untrusted parties, verifying that the computation was done correctly, and paying them for their work.  The enforcement and incentives are implemented as a set of Ethereum smart contracts.

Comment: Skimmed through it out of interest; don't see why not. As a side note, after skimming the first few pages, this sounds a lot like the proposed sharding mechanism for Ethereum and thus may not actually be useful for the Ethereum network in the long term.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, yes, if you follow these guidelines:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

That said, you should try to connect your question with Ethereum.  For example, a question solely about some parameter in the Truebit paper is likely to be off-topic.

The guidelines above also include:

> **Be specific**
>
> If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you
>   give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.
>
> **Make it relevant to others**
>
> We like to help as many people at a time as we can. Make it clear how
>   your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us
>   will be interested in your question and willing to look into it.

As Truebit is highly in the idea stage, it may be difficult to find a specific question that's relevant to others and has a reasonably fixed answer that minimizes speculation on what Truebit and Ethereum will be in the future.

If you're in doubt, try posting some of your top questions first and see how the community votes on it.